# Strapi / Node.js private user uploads

Tags: node.js, node-modules, strapi

What strategies/implementations can be used to allow users to upload private files such as images? At present, the strapi upload plugin does nothing more than upload content to the public/uploads folder, which is accessible to everyone.

I have done a lot of research, but unfortunately I did not find anything. Does anyone have an idea how to call the upload plugin server-side from other controllers/plugins? Would be also nice to know if the file path could be specified dynamically.

The solutions above creating private files api endpoint must not really depend on strapi. It could also be some ideas using node.js (and koa/express.js etc.). Would be nice if someone can give me some keywords or known approaches handling this kind of problems!